# Special Characters are not working in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I take all script tags in separate js file and I call js file in jsp. What I want, text box is not entering special characters. Here my code is not working it accepting special charters also I don't know where I did mistake can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It will be more effective If you reverse your RegEx,
Please let us know, Its helpful for you or not.

```js
function RemoveSpecialChar(id) {
  var specials=/[*|\":<>[\]{}`\\()';@&$]/;
        if (id.value != ''){  
          if(specials.test(id.value)) {
            console.log(id.value+" = Not Accept");
          }
          else{
            id.value = id.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
            console.log(id.value+" = Accept");
          }
        }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtempnum"  name="txtempnum"  onkeyup="return RemoveSpecialChar(this)" onchange="return RemoveSpecialChar(this)"/>
```

Comment: thank you for responding my code is working. where is the problem is i created all java script code in one script js file but it is not saving properly